# Handing Special JSON characters in REDIS using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, redisjson

I am trying to write and retrive a JSON with Special characters to REDIS but the special characters are getting converted

The special character Mój is getting converted to MÃ³j and Můj is converted to MÅ¯j

```
from rejson import Client, Path
import json


rj = Client(host='localhost', port=6360, decode_responses=True)

app_details2 = {
  "applist": [
    {
      "appname": "Mój",
      "country": "PL"
    },
    {
      "appname": "Můj",
      "country": "CZ"
    }   
  ],
  "lasttimestamp": "2021-01-03 12:58:26",
  "loadtype":"F"
}

rj.jsonset('app_details', Path.rootPath(),app_details)
valo = rj.jsonget('app_details',Path('.applist'))
print(type(valo[0]))
print(valo)

for i in valo:
    app = i["appname"]
    country = i["country"]
    print(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by adding a extra parameter to the JSONGET

```
valo = rj.jsonget('app_details',Path('.applist'),no_escape=True)
```

This solved the problem and data is getting fetched properly